# Create expired time, or countdown timer

Tags: node.js

How do I make the time expired, suppose I made an article, to be able to make it again, had to wait for 15 hours, I was using nodejs and node-datetime.
I think the current time plus 15 hours, but how?

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a database with the articles, so, just save the creation date in each article, and when a user requests the access to create a new article, verify if his last article is more than 15 hours old

Comment: I am confused as how to verify, it is best to create the article in time, plus 15 hours, but I don't know how @Arwandar

Comment: why don't you use moment.js for date manipulation
or you can try to do something like creationDate.setTime( creationDate.getTime() + (15*60*60*1000)) to have the creation date + 15 hours

Comment: thankss, i trying using moment.js and working :D @Arwandar